# Google Closure Compiler is importing my extern functions

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I have created an extern in a javascript file and specified it as part of the Google Closure Compiler (GCC) command line option. I am compiling with advanced mode. GCC is taking the function in my extern and placing it in the compiled code. I have no idea why it would do this. GCC is suppose to recognize that the extern function is in a separate file. When I export the object, it will rename the object and leave the object's function names alone BUT it will create a copy of the entire extern function in the compiled code.

I have tried many variations (too numerous here to list) to see how to prevent GCC from doing this but nothing has worked.

My extern:

```
var MyCustomResizer = {
    "onResize": function (a, b) {
    },
    "detach": function () {
    }
}
```

I exported the object as follows:

```
window["MyCustomResizer"] = MyCustomResizer;
```

My app using the "detach" function:

```
MyCustomResizer.detach();
```

My compiler settings:

```
java -jar closure-compiler/compiler.jar \
    --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
    --externs   scripts/externs/resizer-extern.js \
    --js_output_file scripts/release/myapp.js \
    --warning_level VERBOSE \
    --language_out ECMASCRIPT5 \
    --language_in=ECMASCRIPT_2017 \
    --js scripts/base.js
```

And the generated compiled output contains this:

```
ha.detach();
...
var ha = {
    onResize: function () {
    }, detach: function () {
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't export externs. That is pointless.

Comment: I'm not exporting externs. I even left out the line of code window["MyCustomResizer"] = MyCustomResizer; but this did nothing. Leaving that out just resulted in the function call being removed from my code. Now that's pointless. I also followed the identical pattern as I use for using jQuery but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when you specify extern files, you MUST use the --extern option in front of every extern file. I only had it on the first one:

Incorrect:

```
java -jar closure-compiler/compiler.jar \
    --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
    --externs scripts/externs/jQuery/jquery-1.9-externs.js  \
              scripts/externs/third-party.js \
    --js_output_file scripts/release/servetus-min.js \
```

Correct:

```
java -jar closure-compiler/compiler.jar \
    --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
    --externs scripts/externs/jQuery/jquery-1.9-externs.js  \
    --externs scripts/externs/third-party.js \
    --js_output_file scripts/release/servetus-min.js \
```

I find it very strange that the compiler just ignores the one without the --externs but just goes ahead anyway and copies its functions into the compiled code. This should not be allowed and a warning should be issued. This took an entire day to track down.

Comment: Any path without a preceding flag is assumed to be a JS input file. That style is pretty standard by many CLI tools.